# Axon Framework - Configuring Multiple EventStores in Axon Configuration

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, cqrs, event-sourcing, axon

We are having an usecase wherein each aggregate root should have different eventstores. We have used the following configuration where currently , we have only one event-store configured as below

```
@Configuration
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class AxonConfig {
       private static final String DOMAIN_EVENTS_COLLECTION_NAME = "coll-capture.domainEvents";
      //private static final String DOMAIN_EVENTS_COLLECTION_NAME_TEST = 
      //"coll-capture.domainEvents-test";


       @Value("${mongodb.database}")
       private String databaseName;

       @Value("${spring.application.name}")
       private String appName;

       @Bean
        public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory = new 
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);

        return new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory);
    }

        @Bean
        @Profile({"uat", "prod"})
        public CommandRouter springCloudHttpBackupCommandRouter(DiscoveryClient discoveryClient,
                                                            Registration localInstance,
                                                            RestTemplate restTemplate,
                                                            @Value("${axon.distributed.spring- 
        cloud.fallback-url}") String messageRoutingInformationEndpoint) {
        return new SpringCloudHttpBackupCommandRouter(discoveryClient,
                localInstance,
                new AnnotationRoutingStrategy(),
                serviceInstance -> appName.equalsIgnoreCase(serviceInstance.getServiceId()),
                restTemplate,
                messageRoutingInformationEndpoint);
    }

         @Bean
         public Repository<TestEnquiry> testEnquiryRepository(EventStore eventStore) {
          return new EventSourcingRepository<>(TestEnquiry.class, eventStore);
    }

         @Bean
         public Repository<Test2Enquiry> test2enquiryRepository(EventStore eventStore) {
           return new EventSourcingRepository<>(Test2Enquiry.class, eventStore);
    }

    
         @Bean
          public EventStorageEngine eventStorageEngine(MongoClient client) {
        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new DefaultMongoTemplate(client,  databaseName)
                .withDomainEventsCollection(DOMAIN_EVENTS_COLLECTION_NAME);
        return new MongoEventStorageEngine(mongoTemplate);
        }
    

}
```

Now , We want to configure "DOMAIN_EVENTS_COLLECTION_NAME_TEST"(just for example) as well in EventStorageEngine. How we can achieve the same support for multiple event-stores and select the tracking process as which collection they should be part of

Comment: Just curious, but why do you want to have a distinct event store per aggregate?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going the route of segregating the event streams, then combining them from an event handling perspective could become a necessity indeed. Especially when having several [bounded contexts](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html), segregating the event streams into distinct storage solutions is reasonable.

If you want to define which [message source / event store] is used by a `TrackingEventProcessor`, you will have to deal with the `EventProcessingConfigurer`. More specifically, you should invoke the `EventProcessingConfigurer#registerTrackingEventProcessor(String, Function<Configuration, StreamableMessageSource<TrackedEventMessage<?>>>)` method. The first `String` parameter is the name of the processor you want to configure as being "tracking". The second parameter defines a `Function` which gives you the message source to be used by this `TrackingEventProcessor` (TEP). It is here where you should provide the event store you want this TEP to ingest events from.

Pairing them up at a later stage could also occur of course, which is also supported by Axon Framework. This boils down to a specific form of `StreamableMessageSource` implementation.
More specifically, you can use the `MultiStreamableMessageSource`, where you can connect any number of `StreamableMessageSource`s together.

Note that Axon's `EmbeddedEventStore` is in essence an implementation of a `StreamableMessageSource`. Once the `MultiStreamableMessageSource`, you will have to specify it as the `messageSource` for your `TrackingEventProcessor`s of course.

Last note, know that this solution can *only* be used when you are using `TrackingEventProcessor`s, as those are the only Event Processors provided by Axon ingesting a `StreamableMessageSource` as the source for it's events.